# Writing to Active Directory (Windows Server 2008 x86) with LDAP?

Tags: php, active-directory, windows-server-2008

I'm creating a small little webpage that allows a user to use LDAP to search Active Directory for another user by name, and it then returns fields such as address, mobile phone number, etc... The user could then make changes to those fields and it would wrap everything up in a JSON object and throw it back at some php code that would take it apart, and use LDAP to save it to the AD. The query works fine, I'm connected to the server over `port 3268` with administrator credentials.

LDAP doesn't appreciate me using `LDAP_Modify` or `LDAP_MOD_REPLACE` or `LDAP_MOD_ADD/DEL`....
It throws a `Server unwilling to perform` error every time. I am NOT using any sort of SSL connection for LDAP, and certificates are not an enabled role in the domain controller.

TLDR>
I can't write to active directory with LDAP (LDAP_MODIFY etc...), throwing `Server unwilling to perform`, I can only query it and return information. Bind is not anonymous. Doing it in PHP.

What do I have to do to be able to write to active directory?

Comment: Are you a **DOMAIN ADMIN**?

Comment: The account used to authenticate is a domain admin, yes.

Comment: What options do you have set with `ldap_set_option()`?

Comment: LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3 and
LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0

Comment: Have you turned on LDAP_DEBUG_TRACE and LDAP_DEBUG_PACKETS to see if this gives you some help debugging?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'm fairly new to LDAP, and don't know how to access the information those two would give. Also not using OpenLDAP.

Comment: ALSO: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\f686aace694........ does NOT have network service listed as write, but it does have it listed as read. Not sure if this is relevant information. Administrator can't edit properties, only system. I'm a bit groggy, so if it IS relevant could you remind me how to change that as SYSTEM?

Comment: That's not relevant at all. As long as the Authentication is correct, you're good. Let's turn on some debugging like this: `ldap_get_option( ld, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG, LDAP_DEBUG_TRACE | LDAP_DEBUG_PACKETS);`

Comment: Connect, pull some info on yourself or another user, pull some data about an OU and then try some kind of modify and let's look at the resulting debug info.

Comment: Not using Open LDAP or any sort of browser for it, this is all in PHP. Also: Getting "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) " in firebug console with the ldap_get_option line in the code.

Comment: Aw, hell... most of those options require Open LDAP. Sorry, that's the library I use and know how to troubleshoot.

Comment: Ouch, alright. Any idea what it _might_ be? Do we absolutely NEED an LDAPS connection over SSL to write to AD?

Comment: First thing I would try is executing these PHP scripts directly on the DC and see if they work. That will tell you if there's a problem with the remote connection and if SSL is a required component.